# cocos2d-x incorrect touch position on hiding navigation bar on Android 4.x

Tags: android, touch, cocos2d-x, show-hide, navigationbar

I'm using cocos2d-x v3.2 for my game on Android.

While the game is running, if player hides the system navigation bar, then **the game view is dropped down** by a distance equals to the hidden navbar.

And hence, **the touch position Y becomes incorrect**, player need to touch above a button in game to actually get the button.

What I want is to keep game view stay inact on hiding/showing navbar, so that touch position is handled correctly.

Would you please help?

Some notes:

- Navbar is the bottom bar that contains Back, Home, AppDrawer/Menu buttons on Android 4.x devices
- To hide the navbar on rooted device: `adb shell service call activity 42 s16 com.android.systemui`
- To get it show back: `adb shell am startservice -n com.android.systemui/.SystemUIService`
- Some custom ROMs add a button to navbar to show/hide navbar anytime.

Answer (score 0):

i also have been there before

i can fix in this solution

http://pineoc.blogspot.kr/2015/08/cocos2d-x-36-multi-resolution-hide.html

fix some code + add functions

AppDelegate.cpp -> make fullscreen

AppActivity.java -> createView function added

hope this helps